# Export list of positions from animation

Tags: animation, export

I was wondering if it would be possible to export a list of XYZ coords along with the rotation into a file. Not a text file but just raw bytes (see attached example).
I have no clue how python works so that's why I'm asking here.
[image: First set of 4 = X, second Y, third Z, fourth Rot X, fifth Rot Y]

First set of 4 = X, second Y, third Z, fourth Rot X, fifth Rot Y. These are more recordings of my movement and not bakes in blender.

Comment: Is this a file format another software uses and if so, is there a specification of the file format? Blender might already have an exporter add-on for it. Your description is not enough to actually implement it, because raw bytes is very unclear and ambiguous. What precision is used (is it always the bit length as in the screenshot?),  is there some form of serialization (pickle?) going on, how are multiple objects represented?

Comment: It's for modding an old N64 game. The bytes have to be the right endian and can't be bigger than 4 bytes. multiple objects are different files. In theory I should just be able to copy the values from ROM and paste it into RAM with X offset

Comment: I see. This question might get closed as off-topic, but I think it's kinda interesting. How is the rotation stored though? Is it degree, radians, quaternions? Is there no rotation around z?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's in degree's, it loops around once it hits 360 float (for the player that is). 
Also I don't really understand how it's  off topic? I design a whole map in blender, and in game have to move a room around. I can manually input the coords but that takes hours and it's just one straight downward motion.

Comment: Only rotation for X and Y though and no Z? Well, it's a bit specific to your needs, because you basically ask somebody to write an add-on for your. Not a problem with me though.

Comment: oh player wise it's X Y, I forgot the Z axis my bad. I'm used to working with player data I forgot the Z rot existed

Comment: Are the coordinates and rotation in global coordinates or relative to something, e.g. the player?

Comment: they're the "offset" from 0 0 0 or rather just the origin

Comment: Have to lean to this being off topic. Exporting coords to other formats especially text (eg csv) formats is well covered on bse.  The issue then is writing to a binary file with python. which is well covered on https://stackoverflow.com  Can you edit the question re how it is related to blender, and perhaps which old game and a link?

Comment: I'm trying to export an animation made in blender into a binary file, so I can paste it into a GoldenEye ROM uncompressed, which in turn can be loaded into the game through some assembly.